# Simple way to pass object properties to next

Tags: php

This might be a bit hard to comprehend so I apologize in advance if this is not clear enough.

I'm writing my own MVC framework and am once again stuck.

I am in the process of writing the controller classes for the framework. Basically this is how it works:

- Instantiate class coreController which extends abstract class
- coreController sets controller to be loaded by interpreting query string
- query string values stored in variables
- other variables assigned values
- new controller is loaded
- new controller checks if an action object needs to be instantiated.
- new actioncontroller is loaded
- action controller checks if it is the final object required.
- action controller is returned as an object to be referenced during the rest of the script.

generic $controller->method() can be called and references final controller loaded.

Another overview:

```
coreController
    pageController
       pageControllerActionAdd
       return as object to start

$controller->something(); //References pageControllerActionAdd
```

Esentially what I want to be able to do is be able enter a url like:
http://www.mywebsite.com/page/modify/

and have the script pull up the PageModifyController as a variable so I can execute it's methods.

If you can tell me a better method for what I am doing please go ahead. You don't have to write any code, just the idea would be great. It is just that the way I am currently doing is very confusing and hard to debug. I will end up with multiple nested objects and I don't like the concept of that.

I've been reading a lot of other source code and found that it too can be quite sophisticated.

Comment: Well, I've officially been upgraded from a simple framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually created a framework that works along the lines you are trying to implement. I think what you are missing is a RoutingHandler class. Routing is the physical manipulation of the URL, which tells your application which Controller to load, and which Action to run.

In my world I also have Modules, so the basic routing scheme is

```
Module -> Controller -> Action
```

These three items map to my URI scheme in that fashion. Variables can be appended also like so...

http://www.domain.com/module/controller/action/var1/val1/var2/val2

So, what happens after the URI is parsed, and control is passed over to the appropriate controller and action? Let's make some code up to demonstrate a simple example...

```
<?php    
    class indexController extends Controller {

        protected function Initialize() {
            $this->objHomeModel = new HomeModel;

            $this->objHeader = new Header();
            $this->objFooter = new Footer();

            $this->objHeader
                ->SetPageId('home');
        }

        public function indexAction() {
            $this->objHeader->SetPageTitle('This is my page title.');
        }

        // other actions and/or helper methods...
    }
?>
```

In the `Initialize` method, I'm setting some controller-wide stuff, and grabbing an instance of my Model to use later. The real meat is in the `indexAction` method. This is where you would set up stuff to use in your View. For example...

```
public function randomAction() {
    $this->_CONTROL->Append($intSomeVar, 42);
}
```

`_CONTROL` is an array of values that I manipulate and pass onto the View. The `Controller` class knows how to find the right template for the View because it is named after the Action (and in a sibling directory).

The `Controller` parent class takes the name of the action method and parses it like so...

```
indexAction -> index.tpl.php
```

You can also do some other fun stuff here, for example...

```
Application::SetNoRender();
```

...would tell the Controller not to render inside a template, but just complete the method. This is useful for those situations where you don't actually want to output anything.

Lastly, all of the controllers, models, and views live inside their own Module directory like so...

```
my_module
    controllers
        indexController.class.php
        someotherController.class.php
        :
        :
    models
        HomeModel.class.php
        :
        :
    templates
        index.tpl.php
        someother.tpl.php
        :
        :
```

I can have as many Modules as I need, which means I can separate functionality out by Module and/or Controller.

I could go on, but I'm writing this from memory, and there are some wrinkles here and there, but hopefully this gives you food for thought.

Comment: This is an exceptional reply. Thankyou. I'm surprised at how similar your MVC framework is to my idea. My _CONTROL operates in the same way, it just has a different name! What you did there with the SetNoRender is very interesting though. I've only just got into static methods so I'm still trying to find practical uses for them. Even while reading your answer I think I worked out how I'm going to do it. Even just seeing "RoutingHandler class" Helped me a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. If it's of any encouragement, I should add that my framework evolved over 3 years to get where it is now. It's now live on several production sites, and still working really well. Oh... and good luck.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I know it'll be a lot of work to get it to a "publishable" state, but I wanted to do it manually instead of just installing drupal/joomla etc. I like a challenge and I want to know how thinks work. I'm a stickler for having my own solutions. I've been using an initial controller to progressively interpret the URI, loading new objects each time. I think a router would help a lot as I could jump straight to the necessary object.

Comment: Routing is definitely a major help. You can then create different routing schemes if you need to. Do I get a green thingy for my efforts? :)

Comment: I will, but I just want to see if anyone else has any suggestions. "Solved" puts off other answers. Don't worry you won't miss out :).

Comment: I'm with you on the "roll your own solution" thing. Sometimes it's too easy just to use tools without understanding what they do under the hood.

Comment: Just wondering, does everything in your application extend "Application" so you can do Application::SetNoRender();?

Comment: No, `Application` is an abstract class that contains `static` instance variables. It's called on every page so those values are always available. It contains such things as `Application::$DocumentRoot`, etc. It's not the only way to go about it but that was the way I chose, partly based on the way I've seen how other frameworks work.